# rust-analyzer in VSCode does not work in rustlings workspace

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

I'm going through the rustlings exercises, and noticed that rust-analyzer was on but was not generating any inline error messages or type hints. Basically not doing anything at all.

I thought this was because I didn't open the top-level rustlings dir with the cargo.toml in it, so I closed VSCode, then opened that dir as my workspace in VSCode, and made sure the workspace was set as "trusted". Still, nothing from rust-analyzer.

In comparison, I created my own cargo package using `cargo new`, then opened it in VSCode, and rust-analyzer worked fine, with errors and type hints and everything.

Why rust-analyzer won't work for rustlings workspace?

VSCode 1.74.3
Debian 11
Rustlings cloned Jan 2023

Answer (score 9):

It's because `rustlings` has a strange directory structure with exercises in a separate dir from src (or something like that). [See this similar thread on rust forums](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-analyzer-has-no-functionality-in-vscode/79160).

This issue can be solved by doing `rustlings lsp`, after which rust-analyzer will work.